# Tela de splash enquanto recebo dados do web service

Tags: web-service, ios, objective-c, sqlite, xcode

Ola!
 Estou com um seguinte problema: Preciso de uma tela de splash que fique na tela enquanto o app recebe os dados do web service para popular um BD sqlite no iPhone.
 Tentei usar a o image launch do Xcode, mas a imagem so fica na tela durante 2 segundos, e depois a a tela fica preta.

Alguem já passou por isso? Obrigado!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No momento do `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` no AppDelegate, seu app está pronto para exibir o root controller, definido via código nesse próprio método ou no IB caso esteja utilizando storyboard.

Se você fizer a chamada ao webservice de maneira síncrona, dentro de `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, sua aplicação vai ficar parada na splash screen, mas isso não é uma boa prática, bloquear a interface para o usuário.

Entao, no seu root controller, enquanto aguarda os dados serem retornados do serviço, faça o seguinte:

**NO CÓDIGO:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
// crie uma propriedade para poder acessa-la no retorno dos dados do serviço.
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *splashScreenView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Cria a splash view
    self.splashScreenView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
   // define o background
    self.splashScreenView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash-screen"]];
    // cria o spinner
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [loading startAnimating];
    // adiciona o spinner na splash view
    [self.splashScreenView addSubview:loading];
    // posiciona o spinner no centro da splash view.
    loading.center = self.splashScreenView.center;
    // adiciona a splash view na view do controller
    [self.view addSubview:self.splashScreenView];
}

- (void)meusDadosDoWebserviceRetornaAqui
{
    // quando receber seus dados, remova a splash view da view do controller.
    [self.splashScreenView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

É claro que você pode fazer tudo isso com algumas frescruras, tipo uma animação e tal... Além dessa View também poder ser feita no IB, com um arquivo NIB.

Aí é com você!

E o resultado é esse abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sim isso vai ajudar muito!! Vou estar testando e ja trago o resultado!! Ja tinha bolado algo do tipo, mas estava com dificuldade de implementar, seu codigo de exemplo caiu como uma luva!!

Comment: seu codigo funciona!! Isso é bom, mas ele não aparece. 
 Pois oque acontece: O método que inicia o download do conteúdo esta na viewDidload de ViewController.m

 Então quando o app começa a rodar, ele entra nesse método e so sai quando termina de baixar tudo. E não exibe nada na tela, nem mesmo usando o codigo que vc passou. A ideia seria dividir isso em dois processos, sendo o splash a thread principal, e o download em background em outra thread. @Rodrigo Salles

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível controlar a splash para faze-la durar mais tempo na tela.

Sugiro que você crie um novo viewcontroller que mostra a imagem da tela de splash (`default.png`) no método `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` do `AppDelegate` e se quiser, coloque uma mensagem de loading ou um `UIActivityIndicator` para dar um feedback para o usuário que alguma coisa está acontecendo por trás.

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação! Mas vc teria um trecho de codigo mostrando como eu poderia fazer?